# Protractor Javascript pass argument in XPath expression

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath, protractor

I'm using Protractor for my automation tests.
I have a method that selects `state`:

```js
this.selectState = function() {
    element(by.xpath('//*[@id="eligSelfDetails_selEligStateSlf"]/option[@value="Alabama"]')).click()
}
```

and when I'm using that method I'd like to pass argument as `state` name
like this `El.selectState("Alabama")`,
but how do I pass my argument in XPath?

I tried like this:

```js
this.selectState = function(state) {
    element(by.xpath('//*[@id="eligSelfDetails_selEligStateSlf"]/option[@value="\'+state+\'"]')).click()
}
```

but it doesn't work.
It gives me an error:

> Failed: No element found using locator: `By(xpath,
>   //*[@id="eligSelfDetails_selEligStateSlf"]/option[@value="'+state+'"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use string concatenation...

Change

```
'//*[@id="eligSelfDetails_selEligStateSlf"]/option[@value="\'+state+\'"]'
```

to

```
"//*[@id='eligSelfDetails_selEligStateSlf']/option[@value='"+state+"']"
```